# How to properly render images when two Rects intersect in my game?

Tags: android

So basically the game works like this, Whenever the fire makes contact with the icecream, I want a different icecream to be drawn on the screen. A smaller one that would resemble a "melted" appearance. But whenever the icecream and fire collide, the games ends when it's not suppose to.

This is the code that renders the iceCream

```
  private void renderIceCream(Painter g) {

        if (iceCream3) {
            g.drawImage(Assets.iceCream3, (int) iceCream.getX(), (int) iceCream.getY(), ICECREAM_WIDTH, IC3_HEIGHT);

            if (Rect.intersects(iceCream.getRect(), fire.getRect())) {
                iceCream3 = false;
                iceCream2 = true;


            }
        }

        if (iceCream2) {
            g.drawImage(Assets.iceCream2, (int) iceCream.getX(), (int) iceCream.getY() + 25, ICECREAM_WIDTH, IC2_HEIGHT);
//
            if (Rect.intersects(iceCream.getRect(), fire.getRect())) {
                iceCream2 = false;
                iceCream1 = true;

            }
        }

        if (iceCream1) {

            g.drawImage(Assets.iceCream1, (int) iceCream.getX(), (int) iceCream.getY() + 50, ICECREAM_WIDTH, IC1_HEIGHT);
            if (Rect.intersects(iceCream.getRect(), fire.getRect())) {
                iceCream1 = false;
                iceCream.melted();

            }
        }
    }
```

This is the whole class

```
package rect.draw.gametest.model.state;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;



import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

import rect.draw.gametest.Assets;
import rect.draw.gametest.GameMainActivity;
import rect.draw.gametest.model.Fire;
import rect.draw.gametest.model.IceCream;
import rect.draw.gametest.model.util.Painter;


public class PlayState extends State {
    private IceCream iceCream;
    private Fire fire;
    private int fireX = 400;
    private int fireY = 0;

    private int cloudX = 0;
    private int cloudY = 100;

    private float duckDuration = .6f;

    private int playerY;

    private int playerScore = 0;
    private static final int BLOCK_HEIGHT = 50;
    private static final int BLOCK_WIDTH = 20;
    private int fireSpeed = -200;
    private static int ICECREAM_WIDTH = 38;
    private static int IC1_HEIGHT = 77;
    private static int IC2_HEIGHT= 102;
    private static int IC3_HEIGHT = 127;

    private static int FIRE_WIDTH = 75;
    private static int FIRE_HEIGHT = 75;

    public boolean iceCream1,iceCream2,iceCream3,durationEnded;


    private float recentTouchY;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        iceCream = new IceCream(160, GameMainActivity.GAME_HEIGHT - 45
                - IC3_HEIGHT, ICECREAM_WIDTH, IC3_HEIGHT);
        fire = new Fire(10, 10, FIRE_WIDTH, FIRE_HEIGHT);
        //cloud = new Cloud(100, 100);
        // cloud2 = new Cloud(500, 50);
        iceCream2 = true;
       // iceCream2 = false;
       // iceCream1 = false;
    }


    @Override
    public void update(float delta) {
        fire.update(delta, fireSpeed);
        iceCream.update(delta);

        if (!iceCream.isFrozen()) {
            setCurrentState(new GameOverState(playerScore / 100));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Painter g) {
        g.setColor(Color.rgb(208, 244, 247));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, GameMainActivity.GAME_WIDTH,
                GameMainActivity.GAME_HEIGHT);

        renderSun(g);
        renderClouds(g);
        g.drawImage(Assets.grass, 0, 405);
        renderIceCream(g);
        renderFire(g);
        renderScore(g);
    }

    private void renderScore(Painter g) {
        g.setFont(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, 25);
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.drawString("" + playerScore / 100, 20, 30);
    }



    private void renderFire(Painter g) {
        g.drawImage(Assets.gameTestFire, (int) fire.getX(), (int) fire.getY(), FIRE_WIDTH, FIRE_HEIGHT);
        if(Rect.intersects(iceCream.getRect(),fire.getRect())){
            fire.reset();
        }
    }

    private void renderIceCream(Painter g) {

        if (iceCream3) {
            g.drawImage(Assets.iceCream3, (int) iceCream.getX(), (int) iceCream.getY(), ICECREAM_WIDTH, IC3_HEIGHT);

            if (Rect.intersects(iceCream.getRect(), fire.getRect())) {
                iceCream3 = false;
                iceCream2 = true;


            }
        }

        if (iceCream2) {
            g.drawImage(Assets.iceCream2, (int) iceCream.getX(), (int) iceCream.getY() + 25, ICECREAM_WIDTH, IC2_HEIGHT);
//
            if (Rect.intersects(iceCream.getRect(), fire.getRect())) {
                iceCream2 = false;
                iceCream1 = true;

            }
        }

        if (iceCream1) {

            g.drawImage(Assets.iceCream1, (int) iceCream.getX(), (int) iceCream.getY() + 50, ICECREAM_WIDTH, IC1_HEIGHT);
            if (Rect.intersects(iceCream.getRect(), fire.getRect())) {
                iceCream1 = false;
                iceCream.melted();

            }
        }
    }

    private void renderSun(Painter g) {
        g.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 165, 0));
        g.fillOval(715, -85, 170, 170);
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillOval(725, -75, 150, 150);
    }

    private void renderClouds(Painter g) {
        g.drawImage(Assets.cloud1, cloudX, cloudY, 100, 60);
        cloudX += 4;

        if (cloudX > 800) {
            cloudX = 0;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(MotionEvent e, int scaledX, int scaledY) {
        if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            recentTouchY = scaledY;
        } else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (scaledY - recentTouchY < -50) {
                iceCream.jump();
            } else if (scaledY - recentTouchY > 50) {

            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is the IceCream class

```
package rect.draw.gametest.model;

import android.graphics.Rect;




public class IceCream {

    private static final float ACCEL_GRAVITY = 1800 ;
    private static final int JUMP_VELOCITY =-600 ;
    private float x,y;
    private int width,height;
    private Rect rect,ground;
    public boolean isFrozen,durationEnded,isGrounded;

    private int velY;

    public IceCream(float x, float y, int width, int height){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.width=width;
        this.height=height;
        rect = new Rect((int) x, (int) y, (int) x + width, (int) y + height);

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        ground = new Rect(0, 405, 0 + 800, 405 + 45);
        rect = new Rect();

        isFrozen = true;
    }

    public void update(float delta) {



        if (!isGrounded()) {
            velY += ACCEL_GRAVITY * delta;
        } else {
            y = 406 - height;
            velY = 0;
        }
        y += velY * delta;
        updateRect();
    }



   public void jump(){

       y -= 10;
       velY = JUMP_VELOCITY;
       updateRect();

   }
    public boolean isFrozen(){

        return isFrozen;
    }
    public void melted(){
    isFrozen = false;
    }



    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void updateRect() {
        rect.set((int) x, (int) y, (int) x + width, (int) y + height);

    }
    public Rect getRect(){
        return rect;
    }


    public boolean isGrounded() {
        return Rect.intersects(rect, ground);
    }
}
```

Comment: If your application crashes, please post the LogCat message. I also think you might need to post your IceCream code, since it might be the iceCream.melted(); call which causes the issue.

Comment: @AndreaDusza Updated. The game doesn't crash, but it does end in a manner that  I don't to happen. If you look at the renderIceCream method in the second block of code, you will see that The only way for the game t end is when the melted() method is called. Which can only be called is iceCream1 is true. and iceCream1 is true when iceCream3 and iceCream2 are false. As you can see, IceCream3 is true by default, and with each collision with the fire, it decreases to iceCream2 then iceCream3. So the code is being called, but it happens so fast that you dont see iceCream 2 and 1 being rendered.

Comment: So you want to allow the ice cream to collide with the fire 2 times, and end the game the third time the ice cream collides with the fire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem can be solved by adding these two else statements:

```
private void renderIceCream(Painter g) {

    if (iceCream3) {
        ...
    }

    else if (iceCream2) {
        ...
    }

    else if (iceCream1) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Without the else statements, when iceCream3 is true and there is a collision,  iceCream2 becomes true and Java steps into the next if statement where iceCream1 becomes true. With the else statements, this does not happen.  If you move away the fire afterwards by calling `fire.reset()`, your code should work now.